# Unable to find well-known fluid dynamics paper

Tags: reference-request, literature-search, science

I am writing my MSc thesis on a certain topic in fluid dynamics. Of particular relevance to my MSc is the [Stuart-Landau equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart%E2%80%93Landau_equation). In the linked Wikipedia article, they reference a paper written by famous physicist Lev Landau in 1944, *К проблеме турбулентности*, or *On the problem of turbulence*. This is not some obscure paper that nobody knows about - it has been cited by a great many of the other papers in this particular field that I have looked at.

Though it is by no means an extremely important paper to my work, I would nevertheless like to read through it so I can give comments on it. The only problem is, I can't find it anywhere, not even my University's library catalog!

Does anyone have access to this paper? How do I get my hands on it?

Thanks.

Comment: With rather famous scientists such as Landau, their works often get republished as a one or more volumes of "Collected papers". These might be easier to find.

Comment: Such as https://archive.org/details/d.-ter-haar-collected-papers-of-l.-d.-landau